# Can cardinality be defined in ZF-Regularity without the axiom of choice and without Scott's trick?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice, axioms

In ZF-Regularity, can we define a notion of cardinality such that for all sets $A$ and $B$, $card(A) = card(B)$ iff there exists a bijection from $A$ to $B$?

If we add a function symbol C to the signature of set theory as well as this axiom $\forall A \forall B (C(A)=C(B) \iff \text{there exists a bijection from $A$ to $B$})$ to ZF-Regularity, would this be a conservative extension of ZF-Regularity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answers are no and yes. This was proved by Azriel Lévy,

> *Lévy, Azriel*, [**The definability of cardinal numbers**](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-86745-3_3), Found. Math., Sympos. Papers Commem. 60th Birthday Kurt Gödel, Columbus 1966, 15-38 (1969). [ZBL0182.01203](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0182.01203).

The key point is that allowing atoms (or urelements) is something that can be translated to Quine atoms and the failure of regularity, so it is enough to discuss models with atoms.

Finally, to see that the addition of the operation is conservative, note that given any set $A$, we can take the equipotence relation on $\mathcal P(A)$, which is a bona fide relation, and use it to prove anything we need.